# Tortoisehg opens console windows when working with subrepos. How do I stop it?

Tags: windows, mercurial, cmd, tortoisehg, msysgit

I have a mercurial repo with a git subrepo.
Whenever I open TortoiseHG, multiple (5-10) console windows are opened and quickly closed (in less than 1 second). I'd like to make tortoise work without showing those windows.

My best lead so far is [this old thread](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2011-May/031812.html).
It's for SVN, but it seems to be on the right track.

I'm ok with modifying python scripts, though I'd prefer to make it work without resorting to that.

I'm using msysgit with openssh on windows.

Comment: Not sure why Bula deleted his answer (opening TortoiseHg Workbench from the start menu instead of the context menu in Explorer), but it's a valid workaround that fixed the problem for me.

Comment: ...But I just realized that push no longer works from a start menu-opened workbench. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this class:

http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/file/61c8327ced50/mercurial/subrepo.py#l901

That should contain the relevant code. This might also be of use:

http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/file/61c8327ced50/mercurial/win32.py#l281